# imagen in select box

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have modified the mod_language in joomla to put a select box with a image and text.

But I only can put the text withoou image.

I try to include the image like this..

```
<?php foreach($list as $language):?>
<?php if ($language->image == 'en') :?>
    <option dir=<?php echo JLanguage::getInstance($language->lang_code)->isRTL() ? '"rtl"' : '"ltr"'?> value="<?php echo $language->link;?>" <?php echo $language->active ? 'selected="selected"' : ''?>>
            <img alt="icon rss" src="images/footer/idioma_espanol.png" /> Change Language
    </option>
<?php else :?>
    <option dir=<?php echo JLanguage::getInstance($language->lang_code)->isRTL() ? '"rtl"' : '"ltr"'?> value="<?php echo $language->link;?>" <?php echo $language->active ? 'selected="selected"' : ''?>>
            <img alt="icon rss" src="images/footer/idioma_espanol.png" /> Cambiar Idioma
    </option>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and this

```
 JHtml::_('image', 'mod_languages/'.$language->image.'.gif');
```

but in both case I don´t obtain the image

any idea!

Comment: When you say you don't obtain the image do you mean the image can't be found - or nothing displays at all?

Comment: Hi @George Wilson Nothing display at all, only the text, but not the image, It is correct who I obtain the image?

Comment: Indeed the methodology is correct. Where is the image located in your site root folder?

Comment: Hi @George Wilson if I write <img alt="icon rss" src="images/footer/idioma_espanol.png" /> out of parameter <option>  I see the image, but when I put the image inside the parameter opction I dont see the image... How Can I put a imagen inside

Comment: Try rewriting your if() statements with curly brackets. e.g. `if ($language->image == 'en'){blah blah} else {blah blah}` I've not really seen them constructed like you're doing. Because I'd expect you to see something from either the if or the else. Are you seeing any option tags (i.e. is the `foreach` even outputting anything)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following to get the image instead:

```
<img alt="icon rss" src="<?php JURI::root(); ?>templates/yourtemplate/images/idioma_espanol.png" />
```

or if the image is in a component folder, use the following:

```
<img alt="icon rss" src="<?php JURI::root(); ?>component/com_yourcomponent/images/idioma_espanol.png" />
```

Hope this helps